# JsTree: how to select node after insert

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

I'm using JStree v.1.0 and when I click on "add file", I want simply select the created node.

My base code could be found at the page http://www.jstree.com/demo in the section: PHP & mySQL demo + event order

Thank's at all!

**EDIT :**

In addition the code: http://jsfiddle.net/fsQd6/33/
I tried to use the following function (beetwen the /* TODO lines */:)

```
$.jstree._focused().select_node("#node_"+r.id);
```

It seem to work and select correctly the new node...but the parent remain "marked".
Do you know a way to deselect the parent?

Comment: also please provide a jsfiddle like this: http://jsfiddle.net/mmeah/fsQd6/1/

Comment: I cannot replicate exatly the source code because my jstree is connected to mysql. But I snipped a piece of commented code in which there is the point where I think that I need to call the select_node. http://jsfiddle.net/fsQd6/33/ Thank you to the patience. ;)